# Using Html Agility Pack how to select node with namespace

Tags: html-agility-pack

i have html

```
<cr:checkboxes name="name1"> 
  <cr:checkbox label="Checkbox 1" /> 
  <cr:checkbox label="Checkbox 2" /> 
  <cr:checkbox label="Checkbox 3" /> 
</cr:checkboxes>
```

i am using [html agility](https://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) to load html

```
 var document = new HtmlDocument();
 document.LoadHtml(htmlString);

 //select all nodes that starts with `cr:checkboxes`
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//cr:checkboxes");
```

while selecting i am getting exception

> System.Xml.XPath.XPathException: 'Namespace Manager or XsltContext
>   needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.'

Typically, in any other xml document i would have solve this using `XmlDocument` and by adding namespace using namespace manager

How to select all nodes that has name `cr:checkboxes`

Answer (score 4):

This will solve your problem.

```
var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[name()='cr:checkboxes']");
```

I couldn't find another way to support XmlNameSpaceManager with HtmlAgilityPack.